# kafka kraft running in docker and windows wsl2

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, bitnami, kraft

I'm trying to create a docker-compose with kafka kfrat but without success.
I'm using bitnami image instead of confuentinc.
Follow my docker compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  controller:
    image: "bitnami/kafka:3.4.0"
    hostname: "controller"
    container_name: "controller"
    restart: "always"
    environment:
      BITNAMI_DEBUG: yes
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: yes
      KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT: yes
      KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID: "7f29c1ac-01b2-4012-82c7-6f1e8d24dcbf"
      KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES: controller,broker
      KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,BROKER_ONE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: 1@controller:9092
      KAFKA_CFG_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: BROKER_ONE://localhost:9093

    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    volumes:
      - controller_data:/bitnami/kafka
    networks:
      kafka_network:
        ipv4_address: 175.19.0.3

  broker_one:
    image: "bitnami/kafka:3.4.0"
    hostname: "broker_one"
    container_name: "broker_one"
    restart: "always"
    environment:
      BITNAMI_DEBUG: yes
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: yes
      KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT: yes
      KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID: "7f29c1ac-01b2-4012-82c7-6f1e8d24dcbf"
      KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES: broker
      KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: BROKER_ONE
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: BROKER_ONE:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CFG_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: 1@controller:9092
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: BROKER_ONE://:9094
      KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: BROKER_ONE://localhost:9093
    ports:
      - 9094:9094
    volumes:
      - controller_data:/bitnami/kafka
    networks:
      kafka_network:
        ipv4_address: 175.19.0.3

  kafka-ui:
    image: 'provectuslabs/kafka-ui'
    hostname: "kafka-ui"
    container_name: kafka-ui
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker_controller:9092
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: "7f29c1ac-01b2-4012-82c7-6f1e8d24dcbf"
      SERVER_PORT: 8080
    volumes:
      - broker_one_data:/bitnami/kafka
    networks:
      kafka_network:
        ipv4_address: 175.19.0.5
    depends_on:
      - broker_one
volumes:
  controller_data:
    name: "controller_data"
    driver: "local"
  broker_one_data:
    name: "broker_one_data"
    driver: "local"
```

the kafka controller just starts and stops. Is this the correct behavior?

and kafka broker restart after every 10 seconds with this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> requirement failed: The advertised.listeners config must not contain
> KRaft controller listeners from controller.listener.names when
> process.roles contains the broker role because Kafka clients that send
> requests via advertised listeners do not send requests to KRaft
> controllers -- they only send requests to KRaft brokers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be trying to run a broker separate from a controller.

This is an [open issue in the Bitnami container](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues/16243)